# Extract all Urls from a folder

Tags: ruby, url, directory

I want to extract all urls from a folder using ruby but i have no idea about this please someone help me.I have expand lot of time on google but i could not find any suggetion

Thx

Comment: Please give us more information. To begin with: what do you mean by extracting urls from a folder? Do the folders contain files which contain urls?

Comment: By the way: who upvoted this question? It certainly didn't deserve it.

Comment: I download a site using wget in ruby now i want to extract all url (http://example.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org) to parse and search HTML documents.

```
> require 'nokogiri'
> require 'open-uri'
> doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.example.com"))
> doc.css("a").map{|node| node.attr("href")}
 => ["http://www.iana.org/domains/special"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's URI class can scan a document and return all URLS. Look at the [`extract`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract) method.

Wrap that in a loop that scans your directory using `Dir::glob` or `Dir::entries` and `reads` each file using `File.read`.

If you want, you can write a quick parser-based scanner using Nokogiri, but it's probably going to have the same results. URI's method is easier.